# Merge data.frame columns by label attribute?

Tags: r

Suppose you have a data.frame where some columns have a 'label' attribute.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:3], Qr1 = 1:3, Qr2 = 4:6, Qr3 = 7:9)
attr(df1$Qr1, 'label') <- 'dog'
attr(df1$Qr2, 'label') <- 'cat'
attr(df1$Qr3, 'label') <- 'bird'
```

You also have a second data.frame that's similar', but with different variable
stems ('Question' instead of 'Q'). There is also new variable that has a 'label'
attribute of 'fish', and the variables are re-ordered ('cat' is now thrid, 'bird' is now fourth in the sequence.)

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = letters[4:6], Questionr1 = 10:12, Questionr2 = 13:15, 
                  Questionr3 = 16:18, Questionr4 = 19:21)
attr(df2$Questionr1, 'label') <- 'dog'
attr(df2$Questionr2, 'label') <- 'fish'
attr(df2$Questionr3, 'label') <- 'cat'
attr(df2$Questionr4, 'label') <- 'bird'
```

Your goal is to align 'df1' with 'df2' such that 'df3' merges their data with
respect to the 'label' attributes and it follows the variable naming of 'df2' (the one with more of the variables in question):

```
> goal
  ID Questionr1 Questionr2 Questionr3 Questionr4
1  a          1         NA          4          7
2  b          2         NA          5          8
3  c          3         NA          6          9
4  d         10         13         16         19
5  e         11         14         17         20
6  f         12         15         18         21
```

I have tried to rename the columns with the string held in the 'label' attribute before binding the rows with `dplyr::bind_rows()`. This works on my sample data, sort of, but not with my actual data (I think because my label values are very long).

```
# rename columns by label for df1
temp1 <- df1
stem1 <- '^Qr'
idx1 <- grep(stem1, colnames(temp1))
nams1 <- colnames(temp1)[idx1]

for(i in seq_along(nams1)){
  
  lab1 <- attr(temp1[[nams1[i]]], "label")
  names(temp1) <- gsub(nams1[i], lab1, names(temp1))
  
}

# renames columns by label for df2
temp2 <- df2
stem2 <- "^Questionr"
idx2 <- grep(stem2, colnames(temp2))
nams2 <- colnames(temp2)[idx2]

for(i in seq_along(nams2)){
  
  lab2 <- attr(temp2[[nams2[i]]], "label")
  names(temp2) <- gsub(nams2[i], lab2, names(temp2))
  
}            

# bind the temp dfs
temp21 <- dplyr::bind_rows(temp2, temp1)
names(temp21) <- colnames(df2)

> temp21
ID Questionr1 Questionr2 Questionr3 Questionr4
1  d         10         13         16         19
2  e         11         14         17         20
3  f         12         15         18         21
4  a          1         NA          4          7
5  b          2         NA          5          8
6  c          3         NA          6          9
```

Is there a function, or more direct approach, that I could use to to merge these data.frame columns by their attribute labels? Ideally, I'd like to end up with the original variable names of whichever data.frame has more of the stem variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (somewhat less tedious) approach using `tidyverse`:

Define a lookup table for an attribute (`label`) and question (`QR`) in the "larger" data.frame (`df2`) and two helper functions for lookup and reading attributes.

```r
library(tidyverse)

get_label <- attr_getter("label")

lut <- tibble(Qr = df2 %>% select(-ID) %>% names) %>% 
  mutate(label = map_chr(Qr, ~ get_label(df2[[.]])))

lookup <- function(x) lut %>% filter(label == x) %>% pull(Qr)
```

Rename columns in `df1` and `df2` with their corresponding labels, join and rename columns of the result.

```r
goal <- full_join(
  df1 %>% rename_with(~ map_chr(.x, ~ get_label(df1[[.]])), .cols = -ID),
  df2 %>% rename_with(~ map_chr(.x, ~ get_label(df2[[.]])), .cols = -ID)
) %>% rename_with(~ map_chr(.x, ~lookup(.)), .cols = -ID) 

goal %>% select(sort(names(goal))) # optional reordering of columns
```

```
  ID Questionr1 Questionr2 Questionr3 Questionr4
1  a          1         NA          4          7
2  b          2         NA          5          8
3  c          3         NA          6          9
4  d         10         13         16         19
5  e         11         14         17         20
6  f         12         15         18         21
```